# How do I develop a YaST module that is available in the main menu of YaST?

Tags: opensuse, development, yast

I've read the [official YaST module development documetations](http://yast.opensuse.org/yast-journalctl-tutorial/index.html) and I've implemented my YaST module successfully. Now I would like to create a `myModule` menu entry in YaST, i.e., when I type `yast`, to have a menu like `System` or `Network Settings`, instead of needing to type

```
/sbin/yast2 myModule.ycp
```

every time I want to access my tool. How can I achieve this? I have not found any documentation about this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `/usr/share/applications/YaST2/myModule.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Categories=Settings;System;Qt;X-SuSE-YaST;X-SuSE-YaST-Software;

X-KDE-ModuleType=Library
X-KDE-HasReadOnlyMode=true
X-SuSE-YaST-Call=myModule.ycp

X-SuSE-YaST-Group=Software
X-SuSE-YaST-Argument=
X-SuSE-YaST-RootOnly=true
X-SuSE-YaST-AutoInst=
X-SuSE-YaST-Geometry=
X-SuSE-YaST-SortKey=20
X-SuSE-YaST-AutoInstResource=
X-SuSE-YaST-Keywords=myModule

Icon=yast-sw_single
Exec=xdg-su -c "/sbin/yast2 myModule.ycp"

Name=My module
GenericName=My module that does cool stuff
StartupNotify=true
```

Your module should show up in 'Software' category.

Check .desktop files of other modules in `/usr/share/applications/YaST2/` for inspiration (to pick the appropriate category, icon, etc.)